# Dynamic binding for FormControlName in angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to add formcontrolname dynamic in angular 11.I try something like this

```
  data = [
    { type: 'input', name: 'text', title: 'Dynamic Test Testing' },
    { type: 'input', name: 'radio', title: 'Dynamic Test Testing' },
    { type: 'input', name: 'radio', title: 'Dynamic Test Testing' },
    { type: 'input', name: 'checkbox', title: 'Dynamic Test Testing' },
    { type: 'input', name: 'checkbox', title: 'Dynamic Test Testing' },
    { type: 'input', name: 'radio', title: 'Dynamic Test Testing' },
    { type: 'input', name: 'radio', title: 'Dynamic Test Testing' },
    { type: 'input', name: 'radio', title: 'Dynamic Test Testing' },
    { type: 'input', name: 'radio', title: 'Dynamic Test Testing' },
    { type: 'input', name: 'radio', title: 'Dynamic Test Testing' },
    { type: 'select', name: 'select', title: 'Dynamic Test Testing' },
  ];

<form>
  <div *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.type != 'select'">
      <h4>{{ item.title }}</h4>
      <input [type]="item.name" [formControlName]="item.title" />
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</form>
```

But when I inspect the div it shows some like this
[image: output]

there is no formcontrolname attribute present. How can I add this attribute or How can I create form using this **data** object

Comment: You are doing many wrong things. Please Go check documentation for Reactive Forms

Comment: I know but ,I just want to check it is possible or not to create a dynamic form through a predefined array

Comment: Yes, you can create a form from predefined Array.

Comment: Here the stackblitz demo of yours https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ww1947?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Check how to create dynamic Forms with angular reactive forms with the following reference : https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: check the answer mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65517684/multiple-dynamic-submit-button-form-in-angular/65518913

Comment: thankyou sir @MskSatheesh

Comment: Welcome @MohdSabban

Comment: @MskSatheesh sir, I am unable to get data. i try getrawvalue() function.Can you help me little bit more

Comment: You want to take all the fields value

Comment: yes, sir, I want my form value for every feid

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz check there and inform anything needed

Comment: thankyou so much sir you are very kind-hearted thank you so much.I never see someone helping like this.